# Error: The type or name space "GraphQLRequest" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, graphql, using

When I wrote the following code visual studio shows an error which indicates that it can't find something called GraphQL even though I installed the package from nuget on this link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL/ and typed using GraphQL.Http;

```
var query = @"query($id: String) { device (id: $id) { displayName, id } }";
var request = new GraphQLRequest()
{
    Query = query,
    Variables = new { id = 123 }
};
```

Comment: what does the lightbulp tell you to do? did you reference it correctly?

Comment: It only suggested creating a new class. I don't know if I referenced it correctly but I tried to type everything possible. could you check that one please @DenisSchaf

Answer (score 1):

GraphQLRequest is not a class which is provided as part of the GraphQL Package, it is one you create yourself.

For example,

```
public class GraphQLQuery
{
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public JObject Variables { get; set; }
}
```

This class defines the Query and Variables properties you are trying to set.  You will then pass this object to make your query.

The code in your API controller would look something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
{
    var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();
    var result = await new DocumentExecuter().ExecuteAsync(_ =>
                 {
                    _.Schema = productSchema;
                    _.Query = query.Query;
                    _.OperationName = query.OperationName;
                    _.Inputs = inputs;
                 }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Source of implementation for more information: https://github.com/JacekKosciesza/StarWars